# JButton to expand image size pixel to 10% on each click?

Tags: java

This is my TextEditor project when user upload image on it default image size is 400x400 pixels. I added two buttons called `ExpandImage` and `ShrinkImage`. On each click to ExpandImage button image should be expand to 50 pixels.

```
      image = new ImageIcon(filename);
         icon = new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(400, 400, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
         editorText.insertIcon(icon);
         editorText.setEditable(true); 
         editorText.setFocusable(true);



 ExpandImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     // do stuff here

                    // 400 += 50;
                    // 400 += 50;

                     System.out.println("You clicked me!");  
                 }        
             });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     image = new ImageIcon(filename);
     icon = new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(400, 400, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
     editorText.insertIcon(icon);
     editorText.setEditable(true); 
     editorText.setFocusable(true); 


   int point1 = 400;
   int point2 = 400;              

   ExpandImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         point1 +=50;
         point2 +=50;
              image = new ImageIcon(filename);
 icon = new ImageIcon(image.getImage().getScaledInstance(point1,point2,  Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
 //
 editorText.setIcon(null) 
 //
 editorText.insertIcon(icon);
 editorText.setEditable(true); 
 editorText.setFocusable(true);


             System.out.println("You clicked me!");  
         }        
     });
```

you should get the previous value and increment it by the value you want in this case iam incrementing the previous value by 50 . and next call the method to change the icon with the new values. appreciate if you post the output

Comment: Thank you so much its works! but it also showing previous image. do you know how to clear it?

Comment: clearing the image icon ? or set back to default size

Comment: it is showing two images after I click expand button so I want to get rid of old image.

Comment: set a null icon to jlabel and then add the new one ,take a look at the edited post

Comment: setIcon(null); it showing error and says undefined for the type JTextPane

Comment: oops is it a textpane i thought its a label